# Low poly character eye modeling

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap

I have a problem with modeling :

[image]

This is my rough sketch of my character.

Now I applied the face png to the 3d model with "Shrinkwrap modifier".
Result was devastating :

[image]
from this..[image]
to this.

The eyes are distorted and bent so much from the original intended image as you can see :(

I've been searching for an answer to this on youtube but found none so far.

What other ways can I apply the face just like the first image at the top?

++++++ Below is a reference I used : [image]
seems like extrude function was used for this reference character's eyes but how can I select the sections that will look exactly like those eyes??

Thank you for reading this question! :)

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: sure, just sent it!

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=wex4vpjn" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/wex4vpjn/)

Comment: thanks but you need to pack the image before sharing: File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend

Comment: have you tried to simply scale your eyes object on the X axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *Shrinkwrap* > method **Project** / *Negative* / *Offset* 0.01

[image]

Another try to flatten is to change camera **Focal Length**.
Example - from original 50 to 180 mm.

[image]

Comment: Just saw this, thank you! one question is that when I use the first method, there is a slight gap between the eyes and the  sphere at the back im applying to and would just playing around with the offset value the only way to solve it

Comment: What is the question? Yes there is a gap, you can use lower value of course to minimase gap, without offset you will deal with z-fighting :) Another option is to add face expresion as texture with texture coordinates as object directly to head object. Like here for a logo https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/201198/2214