# Creating a custom globe and projecting a map - How to move textures along surfaces easily?

Tags: texturing

I am extremely new to Blender, and I am only using it because there is no dedicated program on Earth that lets you draw onto or place images onto a globe and then create a map projection from it. I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cC1A30mKf0U) tutorial.

What is the best way to add a PNG image to the surface of an sphere and move it around? I don't want the image to be the texture for the whole sphere, I want it to be a continent on the sphere.

How can I move images around on a surface like shown in [the gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnRkK.gif) in [this guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201167/how-do-i-adjust-an-image-on-a-sphere)?

[image]

Can you help me with a basic way/workflow to

1. add multiple .PNGs of continent shapes onto a sphere
2. move them around, scale, and rotate them (preferably as easily as in the gif)
3. project and export the result as a map projection image (equirectangular is probably best?)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I may miss the obvious solution (and maybe someone will propose Geometry Nodes?)

A method would consist on simply create a second sphere, that is slightly bigger than your globe, give it a material with your image on transparent background: Plug your *Texture > Image Texture* with your image into the *Color* input of the *Principled BSDF* and the *Alpha* into the *Alpha*. In Eevee in order to have transparency you need to go into the *Material panel > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend*, and *Shadow Mode > None*. Parent your globe to an empty and rotate with <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> until it has the wanted position. You can create as many globes as you have continents. At the end you'll be able to bake onto a unique image texture if needed:

[image]

[image]

Former solution (Vklidu's): there's a problem with this method as the image will appear at the opposite side of the object, maybe there's an easy fix? Anyway, here is the material setup for the sphere:

- You need to create one *Input > Texture Coordinate* per continent, use their *Object* output, create as many empties as you have continents, select the empty at the bottom of the *Texture Coordinate*
- Put a *Vector > Mapping* behind the *Texture Coordinate*, you'll have to tweak the *Location* values to put the image as the same position as the empty
- Create your continent images (square images with transparent background), load them into some *Image Texture* nodes that you switch to *Extend* mode
- Mix these *Image Texture* into a *Color > MixRGB / Mix* mode, use the *Alpha* output of the *Image Texture* as factor of the *MixRGB*. Create as many *MixRGBs* as you'll have overlapping continents
- Give your empties a *Shrinkwrap* constraint with the sphere as *Target* so that they always stick to the sphere, activate the *Align to Normal > Z* option

[image]

Now when you move the empties, the continents will follow:

[image]

For additional continent, just add a new *MixRGB* node:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a few more questions.

1) My continent PNG is stretching and distorting, as well as mirroring itself at the equator. How do I prevent this?

2) How do I move it around like you do in the gif?

3) Can you show what the mix nodes would look like as I add more continents?

Comment: sure, what questions?

Comment: For additional continents, just add another MixRGB before the Principled BSDF ans so on. For the other questions, could you please share your file?  https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://mega.nz/file/rsY2UIrC#Cmf0oV9cJXNsaI8AK633Rw-7OwtsSMK2O7zdT8jVxxM

Comment: For the Shrinkwrap constraint, activate Align to Normal > Z. For the stretched image, it's probably because you need a square image, crop it in an image editor like Photoshop or Krita

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135830/discussion-between-nicnamsam-and-moonboots).

Comment: @NicNamSam if you find a solution, don't hesitate to use the Your Answer field  ;)